# How do space blankets (thermal blankets) work?

Tags: spacecraft, temperature, thermal, heat

On earth, blankets serve to primarily buffer temperature changes / heat transfer that would occur via **convection** (e.g. a blanket traps air near you so that after your body warms it, it doesn't just get blown away and replaced with cooler air), and **conduction** (e.g. if you're lying on ice, a blanket between you and the ice with poor thermal conductivity will slow the rate of conductive heat transfer).

In the case of a free-floating spacecraft in the vacuum of space, convection and conduction don't exist, and temperature / heat transfer are dominated by incoming **radiation** (from the sun) and outgoing radiation (radiative black-body cooling from the spacecraft, if I'm using that term correctly). (To be clear, conduction *does* exist in space between objects that are in physical contact, but I'm talking about heat transfer through the surface of free-floating objects for the purpose of this question).

How are space blankets designed to buffer radiation?  In the simplest form, I imagine a space blanket would be a thin material that's separated from the spacecraft skin by a thin layer of vacuum, i.e. it would only exchange heat with the outside environment and with the spacecraft via radiation, and so the goal would be to minimize the radiation accepted from the spacecraft and emitted towards the spacecraft.  Do space blanket materials simply have a poor capacity to absorb and emit radiative heat, i.e. they're super reflective?  Or is there more that factors into their design?

Comment: Why would conduction not exist in a vacuum?

Comment: Heat could be transferred by conduction in satellites in space.

Comment: @fred_dot_u conduction does not exist in a vacuum because there's nothing to conduct heat. Conduction is the transfer of heat within a material or through immediate contact. If you're touching something, then conduction works; if you're not touching something directly but there's (for example) air between you, then there will be some conduction through that air, but if you're not touching anything at all then there's nothing that could conduct heat to you.

Comment: The blanket statement, "... and conduction don't exist" is ambiguous and on the surface, false. Conduction exists in a vacuum when two objects of different thermal characteristics are in contact with each other.

Comment: Correct - I was ambiguous in my phrasing.  My question refers to heat transfer in and out of a free-floating object in space, which is in physical contact with no other objects.  In this case, conduction is not a factor, because heat does not conduct through a vacuum.  Made a slight edit to the question to clarify what I meant - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Nice question.  If you believe that one of the answers solves your question, you may accept that answer by clicking the checkmark near the answer's vote count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @PearsonArtPhoto said about the reflectivity, the large number of layers plays an important role in being effective radiative insulation.

To oversimplify somewhat, besides just straight reflection, the absorption and reradiation of heat helps to a large extent.  In general, a large amount of heat energy comes in from one side.  That energy heats up the first layer, which radiates heat itself according to its own temperature, but it does so in both directions more or less equally, which, give or take, cuts in half the amount of heat going toward the cold side.  Repeat this over 40 layers, and it adds up substantially.  Add that on top of the reflectivity of the individual layers as well, and you have remarkably effective insulation.

Answer (score 10):

They tend to be a combination of a highly reflective material, aluminized mylar usually, with a thin mesh in between the layers. The goal is to reflect as much light as possible (specifically those wavelengths emitted by objects at human-body temperature), and keep direct contact between elements to a minimum. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-layer_insulation) has a great picture, shown below.

[image]

Comment: @oldtechaa what could be more explicit than "reflect as much light as possible" ?  All radiated thermal energy is photons.

Comment: That makes sense!  This may warrant a separate question, but if reflectivity and minimal contact are the two central goals, why is the outside of the Soyuz thermal blanket black rather than silver?  For that matter, why aren't all spacecraft shiny and highly reflective?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, that's a fair point. Many people unfamiliar with the topic would consider light to only be visible light, however, so clarification could help them.